# How do you state that something is a "reference" to something else?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

There's a field in computer science called L-System, created by a man called Lindenmayer. I want to write that the *L* in L-System is in "---" to Lindenmayer. What word should I use here? Is it in reference/memory/ode to Lindenmeyer?

Comment: If you wish to use your sentence as is, then _in reference to_ would be all right. You can also modify the sentence and say something like- _The L is named after Lindenmayer_

Comment: I think a suitable word might be allusion, as in, "The *L* in L-System is an *allusion* to Lindenmeyer". Would that be correct?

Comment: Thanks Grace, didn't see your comment before I posted mine. Looks like we posted at the same time.

Comment: You could just use a different form of the word, and say "The **L** _refers to_ Lindenmayer." (or Lindenmeyer)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend _allusion_. "Allusion" is more of an indirect/implicit reference, which you say when you want to talk about something without _explicitly_ mentioning it. Here's a reference on _allusion_ : http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allusion. And in your question, you do want the L to directly refer to Lindenmayer.

Comment: Doesn't the "L" simply *stand* for "Lindenmeyer"? At any rate, the system is named *after* him. The system as a whole, mind you, not the letter, as Grace suggested. The letter is not named after anything, much rather it does the naming.

Comment: @Scot and RegDwight, you're both right but I'm still curious about what word I can use in there, if not allusion.

Comment: *Reference*, plain and simple.

Comment: This may be drifting away from the spirit of the the meaning that you want, and from the scaffolding that you want the word to fit into, but another possibility is "The **L** is *in honor of (what's his name)*". Or possibly *in recognition of*.

Comment: @Scott is right: *The * ***L*** *refers to Lindenmayer.*  Or just *The * ***L*** *is for Lindenmayer.*

Comment: The *L* is an *attribution* to Lindenmayer. Thoughts?

Comment: Is this even a serious question?  It's startlingly obvious that *reference* is the best word for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say any of the following sentences:

> - The L-System, named after its creator Aristid Lindenmayer ...
> - The L-System, which stands for its creator Aristid Lindenmayer ...
> - The L-System refers to its creator Aristid Lindenmayer.

You could even say:

> The L-system, or Lindenmayer system, named in honor of Aristid Lindenmayer ...

Whichever you choose sounds fine to me.